# How to pass inputs (interactively) to a model?

Tags: scikit-learn, predictive-modeling, pandas, multiclass-classification

Let me give you a high-level design (blueprint) of my model.

**Input data:**:

```
CATEGORY    SERVICE     TITLE                               DEPARTMENT

apple       fruits      i love eating fruits.               fruitshop
mango       fruits      mangoes are yellow in color.        fruitshop
cycle       vehicle     that cycle is really expensive.     motorshop
```

I am trying to predict the value of DEPARTMENT (i.e. my output class), by consuming - CATEGORY, SERVICE and TITLE - as my input classes.

**Pseudo code:**:

1. Converted CATEGORY and SERVICE columns into fixed numerical values -

   ```
   df['CATEGORY'], mapp0 = df['CATEGORY'].factorize()
   df['SERVICE'], mapp1 = df['SERVICE'].factorize()
   ```
2. For the TITLE, used NLTK and Tf-IDf techniques to create a sparse matrix with the individual word (tokens) as features and the weights forming the matrix values.
3. Then outputs of 1 and 2 are combined to form another sparse matrix, which is my main feature matrix (It has approximately 1100 features).
   I'm so new to ML that not even sure if step#3 is even allowed (or not even a standard practice).
4. Next, the usual steps are performed like CV, fit, predict, etc.

I am using `LinearSVC` and `StratifiedKFold (n_splits = 10, random_state=777, shuffle=True)` able to achieve a prediction accuracy of 73%.

**Question:**:

I want to pass inputs (CATEGORY, SERVICE and TITLE) to my model and it should predict the DEPARTMENT. How can I achieve this part?

Comment: What kind of model do you have? scikit classifier, XGBoost, LGBM, Tensorflow, Keras or what?

Comment: Thanks Simon. Amidst the long post, had forgotten to put the most important thing. I've edited my post now with the requested detail. I'm using LinearSVC() with StratifiedKFold (10 splits).

Comment: Any advise please...

Comment: If you have already gotten some prediction accuracy score, then surely you have your model set up already. What is actually the problem?

Comment: Problem: The parameter to my `model.predict(X_test)`. Here, `X_test` is as per my step#3 but in run time I have only CATEGORY, SERVICE and TITLE in actual string type. How can I change this to `X_test` format ?